# Script to log in to my local dev environment

Tags: javascript, bash, express, automation, browser-automation

I have a simple login system.  A user enters a username and password, gets authenticated, and is then logged in to the site.

With the countless iterations and edits that I'm making to this app, I'd like to avoid having to type in my username and password every time.  I'm using `browser-refresh`, so any change made to any file restarts the server, which means I have to log in again.

Here is a typical workflow: log in at `http://localhost:3000/login` by entering a username and password.  Once authenticated, the user is routed to `http://localhost:3000/home`.  I'd like automate this workflow if possible.

**Is it possible to write a script (either in JS or bash) that I can run that will log me in automatically (by providing the username and password)?**

If it matters, the app has been written using Express JS.